# How to map a class containing a list within the class using automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have two classes one source and destination each containing lists.

Source Class:CompanyResponse

```
[DataContract]
    public class CompanyResponse
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string CompanyId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string CompanyName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string CompanyDomain { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int Subscription { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime? ActiveTill { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public List<Subscription> SubscriptionList { get; set; }
        }




[DataContract]
        public class Subscription
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public SubscriptionType SubscriptionType { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string SubscriptionCode { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public Nullable<decimal> SubscriptionPriceYearly { get; set; }
        }
        public enum SubscriptionType : int
        {
            AvailableOnline = 1,
            Custom = 2
        }
```

Destination Class:

```
public class CreateCompanyViewModel
    {

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string CompanyDomain { get; set; }
        public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CompanyActiveTill { get; set; }
        public List<SubscriptionViewModel> lstSubscription { get; set; }
    }
```

SubscriptionViewModel:

```
public class SubscriptionViewModel
    {
        public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
        public SubscriptionType SubscriptionType { get; set; }
        public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }
        public string SubscriptionCode { get; set; }

    }
   public enum SubscriptionType : int
   {
       AvailableOnline = 1,
       Custom = 2
   }
```

I want to map these two classes using automapper.I have written the below code

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyResponse, CreateCompanyViewModel>();
CompanyResponse objCompanyResponse = _objCompanyproxy.GetCompanyInformation();
CreateCompanyViewModel objCreateCompanyViewModel = new CreateCompanyViewModel();
objCreateCompanyViewModel  = Mapper.Map<CompanyResponse, CreateCompanyViewModel>(objCompanyResponse);
```

But it is not mapping properly.Please help me how to map two classes.

Comment: Have you created a map for the `Subcription` to its equivalent viewmodel as well? Automapper will happily map collections - if it knows how to (with an appropriate map).

Comment: You also have map some of the members explicitly as some of the properties have different names.

Comment: please give the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this generic method to map your list and assign it to your main object.

```
public static List<Toutput> MapObjectsList<TInput, Toutput>(List<TInput> inputObj)
        {
            var data = new List<Toutput>();
            foreach (var row in inputObj)
            {
                data.Add(Mapper.Map<Toutput>(row));
            }

            return data;
        }
```

You can use it like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyResponse, CreateCompanyViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Subscription, SubscriptionViewModel>();
        CompanyResponse objCompanyResponse = _objCompanyproxy.GetCompanyInformation();
        CreateCompanyViewModel objCreateCompanyViewModel = new CreateCompanyViewModel();
    objCreateCompanyViewModel  = Mapper.Map<CompanyResponse, CreateCompanyViewModel>(objCompanyResponse);
        objCreateCompanyViewModel.lstSubscription = MapObjectsList<Subscription,SubscriptionViewModel>(objCompanyResponse.SubscriptionList.toList());
```